# How to fix "Windows not on boot drive"?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, truecrypt, disk-encryption

This is the message I receive when attempting to FDE (full-disk encrypt):

> #### VeraCrypt Volume Creation Wizard
>
>     WARNING: Windows does not appear to be installed on the drive
>       from which it boots. This is not supported.
>     You should continue only if you are sure that Windows is installed
>       on the drive from which it boots.
>     Do you want to continue?

[image]

(My Windows 7 OS is on the C drive.) 
Any attempt to continue will fail the pre-boot test.

I suspect it has something to do with the 100 MB system reserve partition:

[image]

Is there a solution to achieve FDE here?
I've been trying and failing with this for too long now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the tools states is right. Windows is not installed on the disk it boots from. Pretty obvious that your boot disk is disk1 (the 100 MB partition) and your Windows disk is disk0

On a high level you need to move the system reserved partition to disk 0 which will probably take a backup of c, delete system reserved, disconnect disk1. wipe disk0, rebuild system reserved on disk0, restore c on disk0, reattach disk1

Obviously you will need a backup tool for this and you have been warned that you may lose the ability to boot and or lose your data if you are careless.

Comment: Thank you. I'm considering wether I should follow your plan or follow these instructions http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409
What do you think?
The site appeared when I googled delete system partition.

Comment: absolutely. that should work and is easier. However, ironically, you will not be able to use the Bitlocker full disk encryption without 100 MB partition.

Comment: As if I ever trusted bitlocker.